# What's wrong with this comment in Android Layout XML?

Tags: android-layout, comments

Why does this XML give errors?  (Relevant portion extracted from larger file.)

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!--  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|vertical" -->
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

This gives two errors:

```
Element type "TextView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".  
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use comment inside xml element. i.e. in TextView element only attribules (like name="some value") are allowed.   That should be a fresh question...

Comment: Hmm. Curses upon all XML. Is there not some way to temporarily turn off one attribute?

Comment: I don't know. You can delete attributes and then undo, or cut and paste in comment node outside of current xml node.

Comment: Moving teh attribute to an outside comment works, but is clumsy and easy to forget to fix later.   I find it odd that the inventors of XML didn't think of a universal goes-anywhere way to comment.